# Array of strings of multiple numbers. Math avg

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Please kindly help me with the following string/array mess.

The async function returns the following

[
'0 0 0.33 0.019 0 0 0.173 0.009',
'0 0.133 0 0 0 0 0 0.05',
'0.1 0.11 0.5 0 0 0 0 0.333',
'COMPLETE'
]

how do I find an average of the numbers of each string and how do I push the numbers of each string to its own html table?

I tried some combination of .toString().split() methods and the loops below but didnt get anywhere

```
const parametersOfCRWs = await getCRWs(idle, "worker:1");
let splits = parametersOfCRWs.toString().split(",");
let arr = "";
let sum = 0;
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < splits.length-1; i++) {
arr = splits[i].split(" ");
for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
sum = sum + Number(arr[j]);
console.log(arr[i]);
}
avg = sum / 8;   //always 8 numbers in every string
console.log(avg);
```

average number turned out to be wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "push it to it's own table"?  Do you mean build an `html` table?  or send it back to a server?  or something else?

Comment: I guess he wants to set the average value to its correspondent index

Comment: What do you mean by "the loops below didn't get anywhere"? What did you see that you didn't expect to see?

Comment: yes, html table.

Comment: avg (result of the loops) wasnt correct

Comment: Please revise your post title to be a clear, specific question in sentence format. See [ask].

Comment: Can you give an example of the html into which you're trying to render a table - and maybe what you expect it to look like in the end?  Are you using jQuery?  To give clues on the HTML table solution, we need a little more data.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the strings, add all values and get the result for mapping.

```js
const
    data = ['0 0 0.33 0.019 0 0 0.173 0.009', '0 0.133 0 0 0 0 0 0.05', '0.1 0.11 0.5 0 0 0 0 0.333', 'COMPLETE'],
    result = data.map(s => s === 'COMPLETE'
        ? s
        : s.split(' ').reduce((s, v) => s + +v, 0) / 8
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works even if you have unexpected tokens in your input strings. See snippet below.

```js
const input = [
  "0 0 0.33 0.019 0 fssd 0 dfssd 0.173 0.009",
  "0 0.133 0 0 0 0 sdfsd 0 0.05",
  "0.1 0.11 0.5 dsfsd 0 0 dsfsd 0 0 0.333",
  "COMPLETE",
];

const output = input.map((str) => {
  const { sum, count } = str.split(" ").reduce(
    (avg, value) => {
      const possibleFloat = Number.parseFloat(value);
      if (isNaN(possibleFloat)) return avg;
      avg.sum += possibleFloat;
      avg.count++;
      return avg;
    },
    { sum: 0, count: 0 }
  );
  return sum / count;
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:
(get your own data first, this data variable is just an example)

```js
let data = [ "0 0 0.33 0.019 0 0 0.173 0.009", "0 0.133 0 0 0 0 0 0.05", "0.1 0.11 0.5 0 0 0 0 0.333", "COMPLETE" ]
data = data.map(e=> {
    if(e !== 'COMPLETE') {
        let average = 0
            e.split(' ').forEach(r => {average +=Number(r)})
        average = average/e.split(' ').length
        return average
    }
    return 'COMPLETE'
})
console.log(data)
```

output:

```
[ 0.066375, 0.022875, 0.130375, "COMPLETE" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you a new array which contains the averages of all the numbers in each entry.

```js
const validEntries = parametersOfCRWs.reduce((memo, entry) => {
  const numbers = entry.split(/\s+/);
  if (numbers.length !== 8) {
    // skip this entry (like "COMPLETE")
    return memo;
  }
  memo.push(numbers.map((n) => Number(n)));
  return memo
}, []);

const averages = validEntries.map((numbers) => numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b));

console.log(validEntries, averages);
```

This basically assumes that the `parametersOfCRWs` is an actual javascript array.  So instead of `toString().split(",")` we just use it like an array.

For each entry we split the string by spaces.  If it doesn't have 8 entries (like "COMPLETE"), then we skip it.

If it does, we convert each element to a number so that we can compute the average.